# Cannot find module 'findup-sync' on running grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am working in a project previously built. This project was built using Node and Grunt.
I have a Gruntfile.js in the root folder of the project.

I installed grunt both locally and global, using

```
npm i grunt
npm i -g grunt
```

After, I installed grunt-cli both locally and global, using

```
npm i grunt-cli
npm i -g grunt-cli
```

And when I try to run any grunt command (develop, init, etc), I get the error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'findup-sync'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:8:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I searched in many forums and here too, but I haven't found an answer.
Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE**

After lose more than 24 hours working on this error, I fixed it with the following steps:

1. Install node-grunt-cli in Ubuntu via apt, like [CPBL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159005/cpbl) says in his comment

```sh
apt install node-grunt-cli
```

*On OSX this wasn't necessary.*

2. Following the steps I found on this [blog](https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/issue-on-running-grunt-error-cannot-find-module-findup-sync/). However, I also needed  to run the command

```sh
grunt develop
```

as a sudo, even though changing the permissions of many folders.

Comment: Same here, even though findup-sync is installed (`sudo apt install node-findup-sync` says so)

Comment: See my comment! I'm fixed this error \o/. Maybe this works for you. Make a comment after you try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Pablo Lopes for putting me on the right track (see his question which includes the answer). I resolved my issue by:

1. Installing node-grunt-cli via apt:
   `sudo apt install node-grunt-cli`
2. Running grunt with sudo:
   `sudo grunt`

This isn't an ideal fix because it requires using sudo when running grunt - which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Great Dave! I'm very glad the solution solved for you too! It was many hours working on this :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing via apt was the cause of the issue.  Installing via npm `npm install grunt -g` corrected the problem.  Given an existing global grunt install from apt, you might need to add `--force` to overwrite.